# Get the latest record and count them with time interval

Tags: mysql, optimization, temporary-tables

I have a table as below

```
id   fk_sales_id  status  created_at
1    001          5       2015-02-17 16:45:44
2    001          8       2015-02-18 18:45:44
3    002          30      2015-02-20 16:45:44
4    002          8       2015-02-18 18:45:44
5    001          30      2015-03-01 16:20:44
6    002          5       2015-03-17 16:45:44
7    002          20      2015-03-18 18:45:44
8    003          30      2015-03-10 16:45:44
9    003          8       2015-03-18 18:45:44
10   003          30      2015-03-21 16:20:44
```

I want the latest status of the each fk_sales_id and count how many of them in each status.

- This table contain around 5 million records
- We have 30 status
- Each status I need to count them as below, items(only the latest records) stayed particular status for

  1 Day | 1-2 Days |  2-3 Days  | 3-5 Days  | 5-10 Days | 10-15 Days  |   15 Days Beyond

So for one status my query as below, I need to execute this same query for 30 time to get full report.

```
SELECT 
SUM( CASE WHEN ((date(temp.max_created_at) > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND (date(temp.max_created_at) <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 0 DAY)))  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL0, 
SUM( CASE WHEN ((date(temp.max_created_at) > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) AND (date(temp.max_created_at) <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL2, 
SUM( CASE WHEN ((date(temp.max_created_at) > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 DAY)) AND (date(temp.max_created_at) <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL3, 
SUM( CASE WHEN ((date(temp.max_created_at) > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 5 DAY)) AND (date(temp.max_created_at) <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 DAY))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL4, 
SUM( CASE WHEN ((date(temp.max_created_at) > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 10 DAY)) AND (date(temp.max_created_at) <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 5 DAY))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL5, 
SUM( CASE WHEN ((date(temp.max_created_at) > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 15 DAY)) AND (date(temp.max_created_at) <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 10 DAY))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL6, 
SUM( CASE WHEN ((date(temp.max_created_at) <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 15 DAY))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL7
FROM `status_history_table` AS sh_table
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at, sh_table2.status,
        MAX(id) AS max_soi_history_id,
        sh_table2.`fk_sales_id`
        FROM status_history_table as sh_table2  
        GROUP BY sh_table2.`fk_sales_id`
) AS temp 
ON sh_table.`id` = temp.max_soi_history_id AND  sh_table.`fk_sales_id` = temp.`fk_sales_id`
    where sh_table.`status` = 30;
```

For full report it takes 1 minute, but then I extracted below part(since its common for every query) into TEMPORARY TABLE(MEMORY) after report finished I delete the temporary table, then its takes only around 30s

```
SELECT 
MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at, sh_table2.status,
MAX(id) AS max_soi_history_id,
sh_table2.`fk_sales_id`
FROM status_history_table as sh_table2  
GROUP BY sh_table2.`fk_sales_id`
```

Temporary table takes close to 300mb,

Is there any other way to optimize this query and the whole procedure or different approach? My colleague says use `memcached` but if i implemented this way using memcached we cannot easily query memcached as per I know so it will be useless.

## SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `status_history_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id of the status history',
  `fk_sales_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'id of the sales order',
  `status` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'New status',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'creation date ',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_sales_order_item_status_history`),
  KEY `fk_new_status` (`status`),
  KEY `fk_sales_order_id` (`fk_sales_id`),
  KEY `index_soi_status` (`fk_status`,`fk_sales_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ims_sales_order_status_history_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY     (`fk_sales_order`) REFERENCES `ims_sales_order` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `status_history_table_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `ims_sales_order_status` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5116120 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: How large is the table (number of rows) and how many distinct `fk_sales_id` are there?

Comment: Table contain around 5 millions records total, more than 1 million distinct `fk_sales_id` ids and it will grow.

Comment: So, a sales_id has on average just 5 rows? Hard. Show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE status_history_table;`

Comment: @ypercube i updated the question have a look, actual table have contain few extra columns i have removed them to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1):

First step: This is SQL. You don't need to make separated queries for every status type.

```
SELECT 
   sh_table.`status`,
   SUM( CASE WHEN ( date(temp.max_created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 0 DAY)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL1,
   SUM( CASE WHEN ( date(temp.max_created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL2,
   SUM( CASE WHEN ( date(temp.max_created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL3,
   SUM( CASE WHEN ( date(temp.max_created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 3 DAY)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL4,
   SUM( CASE WHEN ( date(temp.max_created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 5 DAY)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL5,
   SUM( CASE WHEN ( date(temp.max_created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 10 DAY)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL6,
   SUM( CASE WHEN ((date(temp.max_created_at) <= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 15 DAY))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS INTERVAL7
FROM `status_history_table` AS sh_table,
  ( SELECT 
        MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at, sh_table2.status,
        MAX(id) AS max_soi_history_id,
        sh_table2.`fk_sales_id`
        FROM status_history_table as sh_table2  
        GROUP BY sh_table2.`fk_sales_id` ) AS temp 
WHERE sh_table.`id` = temp.`max_soi_history_id`
AND sh_table.`fk_sales_id` = temp.`fk_sales_id`
GROUP BY sh_table.`status`;
```

Comment: yes its reduced the time by more than half.